# How to get an additional search bar in Chrome like Firefox so that I can open multiple tabs from one search

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search

In Firefox, there is a URL section and to the right is another search box that allows me to do a search in a tab, then open a new tab with the same search.  Hope that's clear.  In Chrome, once I've searched, that search is gone as it's replaced with the url that I've chosen.  So is there a way to get another search bar?  I tried the little fox thing but that doesn't do it.

Comment: I don't think such an option exists (maybe with an extension). You could use ctrl + click on a link to open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that exists, but as a work around you can type your search, then ALT+Enter to open that search in a new tab, then go back to your first tab (CTRL+SHIFT+TAB if you want a shortcut) and enter to search.